# Remove underscores from Hibernate generated query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, toad

Hibernate is generating queries like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
backhaul0_.BACKHAUL_ID AS BACKHAUL1_3_0_, dc1_.DC_NBR AS DC1_32_1_
FROM BACKHAUL backhaul0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN DC dc1_ ON backhaul0_.TRAILER_DROP_DC_NBR = dc1_.DC_NBR
WHERE driverday3_.DRIVER_ID = 732
```

But the trailing underscore is problematic when trying to input the queries into SQL Optimizers, as the Optimizer tends to think the alias is a variable. Is there a way to tell Hibernate not to use underscores for alias names when generating queries?

Comment: I don't think you should tamper with the queries generated by Hibernate.. Write your own queries if you need optimization. There are ways to optimize Hibernate, read more about it here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-performance-tuning

Comment: _"Optimizer tends to think the alias is a variable"_, it seems unlikely; what makes you think that? Have you run the query separately without the trailing underscores? What were the explain plans and what indexes do you have?

Comment: @Ben The [SQL Optimizer](http://www.quest.com/sql-optimizer-for-oracle/) would prompt me for a value when trying to run the optimizer on the query.

Comment: Ah, it sounded like you meant the CBO, i.e. how Oracle decides how to run the query. You're speaking about a specific problem with your client? Maybe you should take it up with them?

Comment: Can someone explain what the purpose of the trailing underscore is?